# How to enable the increment and decrement arrows in an <input> element of type "number" in lwc?

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript

```
<lightning-input label="Units" type="number" step="1"></lightning-input>
```

Above is my code, but it is only creating an input which increments/decrements with a step of 1. I am trying to enable the increment and decrement arrow as shown in img. [image]

Comment: Seems like there is an issue with that currently, even in the LWC docs where this functionality is described it does not work in the examples: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-input/example

Answer (score 0):

There have been updates to lightning-input during the Spring'20 release after which the up/down counter was not showing. Use up/down keyboard arrows as a workaround.

It is mentioned in the [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_aura_components.htm&release=224&type=5#:%7E:text=Buttons%20for%20changing%20the%20number%20value%20are%20removed.%20In%20addition%2C%20if%20you%20scroll%20using%20the%20mouse%20in%20the%20input%20field%2C%20the%20number%20no%20longer%20changes.%20You%20can%20use%20Up%20and%20Down%20arrow%20keys%20to%20increase%20and%20decrease%20the%20number.),

> Buttons for changing the number value are removed. In addition, if you scroll using the mouse in the input field, the number no longer changes. You can use Up and Down arrow keys to increase and decrease the number.

Answer (score 0):

One workaround would be using the usual HTML `<input>` element instead of `<lightning-input>`. That way, the arrows will appear. But with this, you can't use some of the features/functionalities that come with `lightning-input` and have to write more code to customize your solution.